# Django Queryset filtrar objetos entre 2 modelos iterando mis valores?

Tags: python, django

Hola estoy haciendo una calculadora de impuestos y tengo que hacer consultas de un modelo y valuarlas en otro.

Explico que quiero hacer.

Tengo los siguientes Modelos:

```
class Tarifa_Sem(models.Model):
    limite_inferior_isr = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    limite_superior = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

class Calculadora_isr(models.Model):
    tarifa = models.ForeignKey(Tarifa_Sem, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='calculators')
    base_gravada = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    limite_inf_calculo = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
```

Ahora el problema en cuestion es que necesito hacer lo siguiente:

Mi modelo tarifa tiene los siguientes datos:

```
 +--------------------------------------+ 
 |          Model Tarifa                |
 +--------------------------------------+ 
 |id |limite_inf |  limite_superior     |
 +---+-----------+----------------------+
 | 1 |  0.01     |       133.21         |
 +---+-----------+----------------------+
 | 2 |  133.22   |       407.33         |
 +---+-----------+----------------------+
 | 3 |  133.22   |       610.96         |
 +---+-----------+----------------------+
 | 4 |  133.22   |       799.68         |
 +---+-----------+----------------------+
 | 5 |  133.22   |       814.66         |
 +---+-----------+----------------------+
 | 6 |  133.22   |      1023.75         |
 +---+-----------+----------------------+
 | 7 |  133.22   |      1086.19         |
 +---+-----------+----------------------+
 | 8 |  133.22   |      1130.64         |
 +---+-----------+----------------------+
 | 9 |  1130.65  |      1228.57         |
 +---+-----------+----------------------+
 | 10|  1130.65  |      1433.32         |
 +---+-----------+----------------------+
 | 11|  1130.65  |      1638.07         |
 +---+-----------+----------------------+
 | 12|  1130.65  |      1699.88         |
 +---+-----------+----------------------+
```

En mi modelo Calculadora tengo los siguientes datos dentro de base_gravada:

```
 +--------------------------------------+ 
 |            Model Calculator          |
 +--------------------------------------+ 
 |id |base_gravada| limite_inf_calculo  |
 +---+------------+---------------------+
 |1  |  1000.00   |                     |
 +---+------------+---------------------+
 |2  |  1200.00   |                     |
 +---+------------+---------------------+
 |3  |  500.00    |                     |
 +---+------------+---------------------+
 |4  |  1600.00   |                     |
 +---+------------+---------------------+
```

Quiero evaluar cada uno de los importes de base_gravada dentro de mi modelo Tarifa_Sem, limite superior y que me regrese el primer valor que traiga haciendo la siguiente valuación base_gravada >= limite_superior y hago un first() para que me regrese el primer valor que sea mayor que mi base_gravada, una vez que tengo este valor le digo que me traiga el limite_inferior y esto es lo que debería de guardar en el modelo, la tabla con los resultados debería de verse así:

```
 +--------------------------------------+ 
 |              Model Calculator        |
 +--------------------------------------+ 
 |id |   Base    |     limite_base_i    |
 +---+-----------+----------------------+
 |1  |  1000.00  |        133.22        |
 +---+-----------+----------------------+
 |2  |  1200.00  |       1130.65        |
 +---+-----------+----------------------+
 |3  |  500.00   |        133.22        |
 +---+-----------+----------------------+
 |4  |  1600.00  |       1130.65        |
 +---+-----------+----------------------+
```

Es decir el primer valor de base_gravada 1000.00 lo ubica en el rango ID 6 de Tarifa_Sem y trae el limite inferior y así sucesivamente con cada valor.

Ahora esto es lo mas cerca que he estado de solucionar el problema si alguien puede decirme que falta.

```
for base in Calculadora_isr.objects.all():
    Tarifa_Sem.objects.filter(Q(limite_superior__gte=base.base_gravada)).values_list('limite_inferior_isr', flat=True).first()
```

Esta consulta la ejecuto en el shell de Django me devuelve los siguientes valores:

```
Decimal('133.22')
Decimal('1130.65')
Decimal('133.22')
Decimal('1130.65')
```

Estos valores son correctos, el problema es cuando intento pasar mi resultados a un queryset únicamente me retorna el ultimo valor:

```
for base in Calculadora_isr.objects.all():
        queryset = Tarifa_Sem.objects.filter(Q(limite_superior__gte=base.base_gravada)).values_list('limite_inferior_isr', flat=True).first()

Decimal('1130.65')
```

Alguien tiene idea de que falta o como podria solucionar este problema.

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que estas igualando el queryset a cada uno de los valores que generas dentro del bucle.

```
for base in Calculadora_isr.objects.all():
    # cuando el bucle haga la ultima vuelta, esta variable se igualara al ultimo valor
    queryset = Tarifa_Sem.objects.filter(Q(limite_superior__gte=base.base_gravada)).values_list('limite_inferior_isr', flat=True).first()
```

Puedes crear un array

```
valores = []
```

Y dentro del bucle vas metiendo dentro los valores, asi al final obtendras todos los resultados dentro del array. Quadaria algo asi:

```
valores = []
for base in Calculadora_isr.objects.all():
    queryset = Tarifa_Sem.objects.filter(Q(limite_superior__gte=base.base_gravada)).values_list('limite_inferior_isr', flat=True).first()
    valores.append(queryset)

# te mostrara un array con todos los querysets que ha generado el bucle
print(valores)
```

O si lo deseas ver mas bonito:

```
for valor in valores:
    print(valor)
```

Comment: muchas gracias es correcto, ahora mi duda es como podria guardar esto dentro de mi modelo, ya lo intente: for t in results:
...     Calculadora_isr.objects.create(limite_inf_calculo=t[0]).save() , el problema es que me crea el objecto en un nuevo campo y necesito que lo guarde en cada uno de los valores que se valuan de base_gravada.